# Pylance and Sympy Object

Tags: python, sympy, pylance

I am working with SymPy package (https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).
The code runs fine, for example, this small portion of code:

```py
from sympy import Symbol, exp, integrate
x = Symbol('x')
f = 2.5*exp(-0.5*x)
integrate(f, (x,0,1))
```

However in VSCode, Pylance always gives me this kind of warning/error:

```
Operator "*" not supported for types "float" and "exp"
Operator "*" not supported for types "float" and "Symbol"
```

Is it normal and is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Pylance does not support SymPy expressions

This will prevent the warnings from appearing:

```
f: sympy.Expr = 2.5*exp(-0.5*x)
```

Or Use MyPy instead of Pylance